# MongoDB aggregate with lookup on object with multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup, aggregation

I have a collection containing objects that each contain multiple arrays. e.g.

```
assmemblies: { 
  mechanicalItems: [{ 
    mechanicalId: <ObjectId that references the mechanicalitems collection>,
    quantity: Number
  }],
  electricalItems: [{ 
    mechanicalId: <ObjectId that references the mechanicalitems collection>
    quantity: Number
}],
```

I'm trying to perform a lookup to get all the fields from the `mechanicalitems` and `electricalitems` into the assemblies collection but struggling to make the `$lookup` work.

When I try to unwind and group I lose the other array or it ends up nested inside each array object in the other one.

I've also tried to directly project back on the quantity property but I'm instead getting an Array of all the quantities:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "mechanicalitems",
      let: {
        mechanicalItem: "$mechanicalItems",
        item: "$machanicalItems.mechanicalId",
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: ["$_id", "$$item"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "quantity": "$$mechanicalItem.quantity" // <-- this gives an array of all the quantities
          }
        },
      ],
      as: "mechanicalItems",
    },
  },
```

I've tried a few other options but can't quite get what I'm looking for.

*** Edit - Expected output

If my `mechanicalItems` fields are: 'size', 'material', 'style' and my `electricalItems` fields are: 'current', 'rating', 'insulation' then my expected output is:

```
assemblies: {
  mechanicalItems: [{
    item: {
      _id: <some ObjectId>
      size: '12',
      material: 'steel',
      style: 'thick'
    },
    quantity: Number
 }, ...
 ],
 electricalItems: [{
    item: {
      _id: <some ObjectId>
      current: '15',
      rating: 'low voltage',
      insulation: 'PVC'
    },
    quantity: Number
  }, ...
  ]
}
```

I'm hoping to swap out the `mechanicalItemId` for the actual objects from the mechanicalItems collection (and eventually rename the field to just "item" but I can do that with `$addFields` or `$project` later).

Comment: What is your expected output? Can provide the sample input & expected output document? Thanks.

Comment: In the $project stage, you might try to $filter the $$mechanicalItem array to pick only the matching one

Comment: @YongShun, I've updated the question with the desired outputs. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is a typo error: `$machanicalItems.mechanicalId`, it should be `$mechanicalItems.mechanicalId`.
2. `mechanicalItem.quantity` returns an array of numbers as `mechanicalItem` is an array. Instead, you need to get the single `quantity` value for matching document of `mechanicalItem` array and set it to the `quantity` field.

```
db.assemblies.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "mechanicalitems",
      let: {
        mechanicalItem: "$mechanicalItems",
        item: "$mechanicalItems.mechanicalId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$item"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $set: {
            "quantity": {
              $first: {
                $map: {
                  input: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$$mechanicalItem",
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$_id",
                          "$$this.mechanicalId"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  in: "$$this.quantity"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "mechanicalItems"
    }
  }
])
```

The logic would be the same for the `electricalItems` array when you lookup join with the `electricalItems` collection.

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aNegM2ICr8k)